# <HTML> Thumbnail rollover image is appearing only in the left of screen

Tags: css, html, thumbnails, dreamweaver, rollover

I'm learning how to design a website using Dreamweaver CS6. I wanted to make a photo gallery that has the thumbnails shown on the page, but when you roll the mouse over them, it displays the full sized image on the left and a little bellow of the thumbnail. Here's what I found while searching the Web (it was probably found here, but I don't remember who posted, so if you posted it, all the credit goes to you).

I got this in my HTML code:

```
   <table>   
   <tr> 
   <td>  
        <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb">
           <img src="productURL" width="100px" height="142px" border="0" />
           <span>
              <img src="productURL" />
              <br />
              <font face="arial">productname
              </span></a>
           </font>
    </td> 
    <td>  
        <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><img src="productURL" width="100px" height="142px" border="0" /><span>
        <img src="productURL" /><br /><font face="arial">
        productname</span></a></font>
    </td> 
    <td>  
        <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><img src="productURL" width="100px" height="142px" border="0" /><span>
        <img src="productURL" /><br /><font face="arial">
        productname</span></a></font>
    </td> 
    <td> 
        <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><img src="productURL" width="100px" height="142px" border="0" /><span>
        <img src="productURL" /><br /><font face="arial">
        productname</span></a></font>
    </td>  
    </tr>  
    <table>
```

And then this on my CSS:

```
.thumbnail{    
position: relative;    
z-index: 0;    
}

.thumbnail:hover{    
background-color: transparent;    
z-index: 50;    
}

.thumbnail span{     
position: absolute;    
background-color: lightyellow;    
padding: 5px;    
left: 1000px;    
border: 1px dashed gray;    
visibility: hidden;    
color: black;    
text-decoration: none;    
}

.thumbnail span img{     
border-width: 0;    
padding: 2px;    
}

.thumbnail:hover span {    
visibility: visible;    
top: 300px;    
left: 107px;
}
```

I thought this was a pretty good code, however I can't figure out how to make the image pop up right next to the thumbnail. I tried to create a "subclass" called "span_2" but it didn't come out right, and messed the whole page.

I think this is a big question, but I need help. I started playing around with HTML this week.

EDIT

Is there any function where I can pick the location of the thumbnail and set the picture to be displayed right next to it?

Comment: You should check your HTML - you got lots of wrongly closed tags. Also the `<font>`-tag is deprecated.

Comment: Exactly. I formatted your first snippet to make it more clear. `<a>`, `<span>` and `<font>` are totally twisted

Comment: @insertusernamehere thank you for the help with code and for formating :)

Comment: http://scripterlative.com/files/thumbsmart.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I make a valid new code to your website : http://jsfiddle.net/sMLbP/4/

There is HTML :

```
<div class="container_image">
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><img src="productURL" width="100px" height="142px" border="0" /></a>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="productURL" />
        <span style="font-family:arial"> productname</span>
    </div> 
</div>
<div class="container_image">
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><img src="productURL" width="100px" height="142px" border="0" /></a>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="productURL" />
        <span style="font-family:arial"> productname</span>
    </div> 
</div>
<div class="container_image">
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><img src="productURL" width="100px" height="142px" border="0" /></a>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="productURL" />
        <span style="font-family:arial"> productname</span>
    </div> 
</div>
<div class="container_image">
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><img src="productURL" width="100px" height="142px" border="0" /></a>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="productURL" />
        <span style="font-family:arial"> productname</span>
    </div> 
</div>
```

[UPDATED] There is CSS:

```
.container_image {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    margin-right:20px;
}

.container_image:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
}

.container_image .image {
    position: absolute !important ;
    background-color: lightyellow;
    border: 1px dashed gray;
    top: -1000px !important ;
    z-index:10 !important ;
}

.container_image:hover .image {
    left: 100px !important ; 
    top:0px !important ;
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't work for me.The image that pops out is still aligned to the top of the page. Maybe is something to do with the rest of my code?

Comment: Which browser and version did you use, what contain the code I provide to you ?

Comment: I update my CSS code, replace yours and refresh cache with CTRL + R.

Comment: I'm using the DreamWeaver design view, Google Chrome 25.0.1364.97m and IE9 9.0.8112.16421 64-bit

Comment: So try the new CSS above, may be you specify after a new properties for your images.

Comment: It didn't work either. I'll just create a table with a nice border and have the "pop-ups" displayed there. But thanks a lot for your help. I learned a bit watching the codes

Comment: Try to remove your table, or just put it in a blanked page encapsulated by 
`<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>yourpage</title></head><body> CODE THERE </body></html>`, then add your code.

Comment: When I put the code you wrote out of the table or in the table, the image is aligned to the top of the page. But when i put in a brand new blank page, the code works perfecly, thats why I tought there might be some issue with my page code

Comment: So I recommand you to add your code step by step to your new code. Indeed, you have to identify the issue or your website can have unwanted behaviors. I think you can close the question now.

Comment: OK, i'll do that then. One last question, how do I close the question?

Comment: Just accept my answer by clicking near arrow at top of my question. You can have information about stack overfow there : http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking in the right direction there with the span element.

Look into `display:block;` it makes any elements of the page behave as a block element (e.g. div)

Also in width and height of an image you usually do not use units.

Go to online resources like this: http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp

to learn some basics of html.

Comment: Where should I put the `display:block;`? I am pretty new to the HTML language. Also, regarding the usage of units, its just a habbit. I've had problems not using units while tanking tests in High Scholl hahaha

Comment: you add the display property to the span and the a tag ... to so that they behave the way you want on the page ... read here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp the w3schools is an excellent way to start learning html.

Comment: @MartinTurjak You should read this article about W3Schools references : http://w3fools.com/

Comment: @MilchePatern Whoa, thats a surprise

Comment: @MilchePatern Hehe. Yes ... I know this page. However, I believe that for a total beginner a page (not necessarily w3s) with a reasonably good overview offers a very good start - however "authoritatively" written it might be, and when the noob learns some ... and reads other pages, blogs, whatever resources he finds, he will form his own opinion ;-)